# Dragging in Trackpad's accessibility setting gets randomly turned off

Tags: macos, mojave, trackpad

I enable System Preferences → Accessibility Mouse & Trackpad → Trackpad Options → Enable dragging. However, it gets unchecked (disabled) on its own. It happens after  a few hours, as I face this issue at least once a day.

[image: System Preferences ss]

Does anyone know the cause or the solution? I'm using 13" 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.5. Nothing else is installed that can muddle the Trackpad settings.